# How does one properly regenerate python .pb2.py files from .proto files using protocol buffer compiler for tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, protocol-buffers, bazel, tensorflow-serving

Using the incepetion_inference.proto as an example, I attempted to regenerate the  inception_inference.pb2.py file using the command:

protoc inception_inference.proto --python_out=./

Comparing the newly generated file, inception_inference.pb2.py with the one generated originally from the compile, it is identical except for the license notication, and the bottom portion which contains:

```
import abc
import six
from grpc.beta import implementations as beta_implementations
from grpc.framework.common import cardinality
from grpc.framework.interfaces.face import utilities as face_utilities

class BetaInceptionServiceServicer(six.with_metaclass(abc.ABCMeta, object)):
  """<fill me in later!>"""
  @abc.abstractmethod
  def Classify(self, request, context):
    raise NotImplementedError()

class BetaInceptionServiceStub(six.with_metaclass(abc.ABCMeta, object)):
  """The interface to which stubs will conform."""
  @abc.abstractmethod
  def Classify(self, request, timeout):
```

And so on and so forth...

I'm guessing some part of the Bazel build system injects this into the .pb2.py file, but I cannot find where this is done.

Anyone know how to regenerate this file properly?   Obviously, understanding this is a required step in generating my own .proto file.

Thanks!

Comment: For each proto file there's a proto_library BUILD target, the proper way is to bazel build that target

Comment: Yes, in this case: 
serving_proto_library(
    name = "inception_inference_proto",
    srcs = ["inception_inference.proto"],
    has_services = 1,
    cc_api_version = 2,
    cc_grpc_version = 1,
)   As stated above, regenerating doesn't work out of the box.

Comment: Have you tried doing `bazel build ...:inception_inference_proto`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
protoc -I ./ --python_out=. --grpc_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=`which grpc_python_plugin` ./your.proto
```

Make sure you've installed protoc 3.0 (C++ and python plugin) as well as maybe running a pip install on grpcio if you haven't already.